# How do I make the list output from the 'by' function in R usable?

Tags: r

I have a set of data with a dependent variable and two factors.  I would like randomly sample the dependent variable (with replacement) within each subset of combinations of my two factors (and the number of random samples retrieved should equal the number that existed originally at each combination of the two factors).  I've been able to do this using the 'by' function.  The problem is the output is a list and I'd like something more accessible but haven't had any luck converting to a data frame.  My end goal is to run the simulation described above 1000 times and for each simulation calculate the average of the random samples retrieved for each combination of the factors.

This produces the dataset:

```
value<-runif(100,5,25)
cat1<-factor(rep(1:10,10))
a<-rep("A",50)
b<-rep("B",50)
cat2<-append(a,b)
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(value,cat1,cat2))
```

This creates one simulation of random values drawn from the factor levels and 
stores that info in a list:

```
list<-by(data[,"value"],data[,c("cat1","cat2")],function(x) sample(x,length(x),T))
```

What I'd like to do is wind up with a dataframe that has as columns "Simulation", "AverageValue", "cat1", and "cat2" - so that I would have 1000 simulation lines for each combination of cat1 and cat 2.

Any suggestions on how to make the 'by' output more accessible so I can run a for loop on the output or other suggestions would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: give a try to `do.call(rbind, list)` should do the trick.

Comment: Warning message:
In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 12)

Comment: Thanks, SabDeM.  Your solution worked great for the simulated data set above.  The issue I'm having still though in running that bit of code on my actual data is that the number of simulated values for each factor combination is not equal for all factor combinations. And so the number of columns for each row are not equivalent, and I get the error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a more general method, you might like to use `dplyr` rather than `by`. this way you'll keep your data.frame.

In this case, you would use `group_by` to group by your cat1 and cat2, rather than `by`, and use `mutate` to add a new column on. You could replace `new =` with `value =` if you don't want to keep your old data:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(cat1, cat2) %>%
         mutate(new = sample(value, length(value), replace = T))

Source: local data frame [100 x 4]
Groups: cat1, cat2 [20]

              value   cat1   cat2              new
             (fctr) (fctr) (fctr)           (fctr)
1  13.9639607304707      1      A 13.2139691384509
2  22.6068278681487      2      A 5.27278678957373
3  24.6930849226192      3      A 22.0293137291446
4   16.842244095169      4      A 9.56347029190511
5   18.467006101273      5      A 23.1605510273948
6  20.6661582039669      6      A 24.3043746100739
7  9.37060782220215      7      A 13.9268753770739
8  6.68592340312898      8      A  20.034239795059
9  6.95704637560993      9      A  12.676755907014
10 17.2769332909957     10      A  24.453850784339
..              ...    ...    ...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do and it works perfectly.  Thanks, jeremycg!

Comment: I was able to use the suggestion above to generate output with my data, but it seems the random sample of 'value' is drawn from the entire distribution of 'value'.  What I was looking for was a solution that drew at random with replacement, but only from combined levels of cat1 and cat2, not from the entire distribution of value.